# How does one debug or query the local datastore in flutter

Tags: aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify, aws-datastore

I am using `aws-amplify` and `aws-datastore` plugins in my Flutter ios app as the backend is AWS.

I would like to see the values of the `Models` in the local datastore. I don't want to query the datastore in code. I actually want to see the value in the DB engine.

Below is the browser implementation which I am trying to get at.
[image]

When I do step debugging I can't the values from the DB engine which makes sense. Below is a screenshot. How does one see the local DB values in Flutter?

[image]

I also tried to get some inspiration from the [Flutter docs on SQLlite](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) but they have no information on DB management. Please share some insights on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter DevTools to inspect the local database involves a few steps. Here's a general outline of how you can do it:

1. Start Flutter DevTools:

   - Open a terminal window.
   - Navigate to your Flutter app's directory.
   - Run the command: `flutter pub global run devtools`.
   - This will start the DevTools server.
2. Connect DevTools to your App:

   - Open your Flutter app in a browser by visiting `http://localhost:9100`.
   - Make sure your app is running or paused at a breakpoint.
3. Inspect the Local Database:

   - In the DevTools UI, go to the "Database" tab.
   - Select the SQLite database you want to inspect. You might need to find the exact location of your app's database file.
   - DevTools will display the tables and data within the database.
   - You can run SQL queries, view table data, and even modify data if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, this did not work for the AWS datastore. Pls see the comment from Payal Sonawane